# How to place Left Navigation Bar behind Status Bar? - SystemUI - Android - AOSP

Tags: android, android-source, android-windowmanager

I've customised Bottom Navigation Bar into Left Side Navigation Bar using TYPE_NAVIGATION_BAR_PANEL in Android AOSP Project. But the problem is it overlaps the Status Bar. Need to put Navigation Bar behind Status Bar.

Comment: No, this not Navigation Drawer, this is an actual Navigation Bar (with back, home, recent buttons) that's been added by using WindowManager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it was intended. StatusBar has lower layer type than navigation type. Which means navigation view is in front of StatusBar.

```
/**
 * Window type: the status bar.  There can be only one status bar
 * window; it is placed at the top of the screen, and all other
 * windows are shifted down so they are below it.
 * In multiuser systems shows on all users' windows.
 */
public static final int TYPE_STATUS_BAR         = FIRST_SYSTEM_WINDOW;
.....
/**
 * Window type: Navigation bar (when distinct from status bar)
 * In multiuser systems shows on all users' windows.
 * @hide
 */
public static final int TYPE_NAVIGATION_BAR = FIRST_SYSTEM_WINDOW+19;
```

As a walk around, You can modify the layout param of navigation bar. You can set y to `getStatusBarHeight()` and gravity to `Gravity.BOTTOM` - Never tested.